# Where should I put the localStorage in this code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the dark/light mode theme on my site store locally so that it doesnt untoggle every time a new page is opened or the site is refreshed. Where should I put the `localStorage.`? Or is the whole thing wrong?

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
        
        checkbox.addEventListener('change',()=> {
          // change theme of website
          document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using vanilla javascript i.e on you html you've loaded your script as below

```
<html>
...

<script src='/to/scripts.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can add two functions, one which set the them to localStorage and the other which reads it and make it accessible.

on update the update function sets the new value for the theme,
on read  the read function reads the stored value even after refresh/reloads
as below

```
<html>
  ....
 <script>
  //for setting
   const toggleTheme = () => {
      if(localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark'){
         localStorage.setItem('theme','light')
      }else{
          localStorage.setItem('theme','dark')
       }
   }
  //for reading
   const theme = () => localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light'
 </script>

 <script src='/to/scripts.js'></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How does this relate to the code OP provided? Why are you telling OP how to load an external JS file?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit (last answer was not solving the problem)**

I think you can use `DOMContentLoaded` event to set the theme from `localStorage`, when the checkbox changes you set the selected theme on the storage. This way when the page reloads, it will look for the theme and set it, if theme is not set, it will default to light.

Here is a sample:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if(theme === undefined) theme = 'light';
  document.body.classList.add(theme);
});

const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('change',(e) => {
    const theme = e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'light';
  localStorage.setItem(theme);
  document.body.classList.add(theme);
});
```

Comment: OP knows they can use `localStorage` since the title of the question clearly states they are trying to use it. OP is asking _where_ in their code they should set the `localStorage` value.

Comment: @disinfor just updated my answer, does it answer the question now?